# How to add a text and value to NSComboBox?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, monomac, xamarin.mac

I have list of Employees with Name and EmployeeNo, how can we add this to NsComboxBox something like we do in Windows dropdownlist as Text and value. I could only add the text using NsCombobox.Add("EmployeeName").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [Working with Menu Controls](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/standard-controls/#Working_with_Menu_Controls) section of our **Standard Controls** document. If you are still having an issue, please let me know and I'll see if I can't help you out.